# How to get the coastline from OSM?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill

I've successfully imported all data for Sweden to my PostGIS database. Right now I'm designing my map in Tilemill with OSM Bright as base.

But I've got a major problem: where is the coastline? Right now all the roads and buildings are on the water. I've looked through all three `landusages` tables, and the only relevant geometry types are `land` and `island`, but they aren't what I expected.

I'm a GIS rookie, so any help is appreciated. :-)

Comment: Where did you get your source OSM data from?

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/

Comment: http://downloads.cloudmade.com/europe/northern_europe/sweden#downloads_breadcrumbs has Swedish Coastline separately

Comment: Ah nice! I tried to import that with `imposm`, but no new table was created. Have I missed something?

Comment: Because of their complexity, separate tools are used to process OpenStreetMap coastlines into shapefiles instead of loading them into PostgreSQL. TileMill should have downloaded these automatically when you loaded your OSM Bright project.

Find the layers named "processed_p" and "shoreline_300" in your project. Do they point to "http://tilemill-data.s3.amazonaws.com/osm/coastline-good.zip" and "http://tilemill-data.s3.amazonaws.com/osm/shoreline_300.zip" respectively?

Comment: I didn't notice that, haha. Then I spent a whole day in vain. How ever, the `coastline-good.zip` is over 300 MB, so Tilemill crashes everytime I open the project. So I removed it and now rely completely on `10m-land.zip` together with `shoreland_300.zip`. The coastline is there now, so I've no idea what that 300 MB was for. Anyway, problem solved!

Answer (score 6):

On https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/, you can download pre-processed land polygons, water polygons and coastlines. They are derived from the OSM data and updated daily.

Land or water polygons are especially interesting in your case, as you won't have to manually close the coastline.